# How to remove and print every item in an IntStack object until it is empty?

Tags: java, stack, peek

I am having trouble figuring out how to remove and print every item in an IntStack object until it is empty. Would I need to use an if statement? I know the basics of stacks, for example:
Suppose s refers to an IntStack object.

If I wanted to add the value 100 to the top of s, I would simply use `s.push(100)`

If I wanted to remove and print the top value of s, I would use `s.pop()`

If I wanted to print the top value without removing it, I would use `s.peek()`

I run into trouble once I try to remove and print every item in s until it is empty.

Comment: `IntStack` is not a standard JDK class. Which library are you using?

Comment: What trouble do you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even If InStack is some third party stack, as per the description in question it implements all the standard stack methods, so following should work.

```
public void print(Stack s)
{
   while(!s.isEmpty())
   {
       System.out.println(s.pop());
   }

}
```

Comment: Why not `System.out.println(s.pop())`?

Comment: @JTeam May I ask what the "!" does in (!s.isEmpty)?

Comment: It is not operator of JAVA - execute the code inside while loop ->  while stack is not empty. You can read the basic java operators on internet.

Answer (score -1):

Assumming when there is nothing in the stack, s.peek() will return `null`,

```
while(s.peek() != null){
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

Comment: Whatever `IntStack` is, it probably holds primitives.